# Interfacing with BME280 via STM8L101F3 via SPI

Tags: spi, stm8

I'm trying to use the BME280 via an STM8L101F3. However I cannot seem to get any data from the sensor. As a start I would like to read the chip ID to verify that everything is working. However, I have not found a suitable library that works with the STM8L10x and I have been unable to create my own. I have the following code but all I receive are zero's. I have tried everything I could find online but I haven't progressed. I have checked that the sensor is functioning with an arduino and I'm using 4-wire spi.

```
#include "stm8l10x.h"
#include "bme280.h"

void DelayS(uint16_t sec) {
  uint32_t freq = 400000;
  for (; sec != 0; sec--) {
    freq = 400000;
    for (; freq != 0; freq--) {
    }
  }
}

static void SPI_Config(void)
{
  /*Set the MOSI,MISO and SCK at high level*/
  GPIO_ExternalPullUpConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7, ENABLE);
  // Disable SPI before configuration
  SPI_DeInit();
  /* Initialize SPI in Slave mode  */
  SPI_Init(SPI_FirstBit_MSB, SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_8, SPI_Mode_Master, SPI_CPOL_Low,
           SPI_CPHA_1Edge, SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex, SPI_NSS_Soft);
}

void main(void)
{
  volatile uint8_t received = 33;
  volatile uint8_t sendByte = 0xD0; // ChipID register
  /* High speed internal clock prescaler: 1*/
  CLK_MasterPrescalerConfig(CLK_MasterPrescaler_HSIDiv1);
  // Disable SPI for configuration
  SPI_Cmd(DISABLE);
  /* Enable SPI clock */
  CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_Peripheral_SPI, ENABLE);
  SPI_Config();
  // Init CSB
  GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB);
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_1, GPIO_Mode_Out_PP_High_Fast);
  // Enable SPI
  SPI_Cmd(ENABLE);
  // Wait for SPI to be idle
  while (SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI_FLAG_BSY)) {};
  DelayS(5);
  // Begin Transaction, pull CSB low
  GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_1, RESET);
  // Write to ChipId register
  SPI_SendData(sendByte);
  // Wait for buffer to be empty
  while (SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI_FLAG_TXE) == RESET) {};
  // Wait for the register to be filled
  while (SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET) {};
    // Receive the data
    received = SPI_ReceiveData();
  // End transaction, pull CSB high
  GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_1, SET);
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *   where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval : None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif
```